# how to add active class only one li using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://plnkr.co/edit/9oAmucEO0yvYDJJi8tGK?p=preview

Hello
I am adding active class on footer while scrolling.Actually When user scroll it check `div` come is viewport if yes it add active class in footer.But At some time when two div's are in viewport s two item selected .But I need only one item is slected .IS there a any event `will check`diventer`in viewport or`exit` in viewport .If i got this then I am able to select only one item in footer

```
$(function () {
    $("#container").scroll(function () {
      console.log('scrolling');
      $('#container > div').each(function (i, left) {
        console.log(this)
        console.log($(this))
        var md = $(this).attr('data-msid');
        console.log($(this).isOnScreen())
        if($(this).isOnScreen()){
            $('.fC li[data-msidatrr='+md+']').addClass('active');
        }else {
          $('.fC li[data-msidatrr='+md+']').removeClass('active');
        }
      })
    });
    $.fn.isOnScreen = function () {

      var win = $(window);

      var viewport = {
        top: win.scrollTop(),
        left: win.scrollLeft()
      };
      viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
      viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

      var bounds = this.offset();
      bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
      bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

      return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));


    }
  })
```

Comment: How do you wish to determine which of the elements should have the `active` class-name; the last one to enter the viewport, the element containing the largest percentage of the viewport, some other metric?

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line

```
$('.item').removeClass('active');
```

The resulting code in if statement will be then:

```
if($(this).isOnScreen()){
        $('.item').removeClass('active');
        $('.fC li[data-msidatrr='+md+']').addClass('active');
    }
```

Explanation:
First remove active class from all the list and then add only for needed one.

Comment: pls share plunker

Comment: I just added `$('.item').removeClass('active');` before `$('.fC li[data-msidatrr='+md+']').addClass('active');` . Nothing more than that. It will work

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, I didn't even test it. @user5711656 is it too difficult to test by a simple cut and paste?

Answer (score 0):

i think i found a solution for you.

First, you need to change the `$("#container").scroll` callback to this:

```
  var elActive = null;
  $('.fC li').removeClass('active');
  $('#container > div').each(function (i, left) {
    var md = $(this).attr('data-msid');
    if($(this).isOnScreen()){
        elActive = $('.fC li[data-msidatrr='+md+']');
        //return false; // uncomment to get the first of the list
    }
  });
  if( elActive ) elActive.addClass('active');
```

this will remove the class `active` from all the `li` items and will iterate over all the `div`s, checking which is *on screen* and putting the `li` for that element on variable `elActive`.
After that, add the cass to the `elActive` element.

But the behavior still strange only with this change, i think you can also change the `$.fn.isOnScreen` function to this:

```
  var win = this.closest('[scrollable]') || $(window);

  var viewport = {
    top: win.scrollTop(),
    left: win.scrollLeft()
  };
  viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
  viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

  var bounds = this.offset();
  bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
  bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

  return (
        !(viewport.right < bounds.left 
          || viewport.left > bounds.right 
          || viewport.bottom < bounds.top 
          || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
```

This will not check the scrollTop anymore, now is checked the offset bounds of the scrollable area (our new *"viewport"*) and the offset of the elements inside it (the `this` reference inside the function) to tell us if that element is on screen or not.
Add the `scrollable` attribute to the `#container` element to see this working.

I think this changes will give you with the behavior you're expecting.

Here is a fork of your example, with the changes i say:
https://plnkr.co/edit/bK1h0YF2tabiWPpjQUNh?p=preview

Comment: pls share plunker